# SimpleXml: How to set name when using ElementUnionList

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I'm using SimpleXml to read/write configurations from a Java object structure.  I have a List containing instances of various subclasses.  I'd like each subclass to be indicated by the XML element, but I also want to specify the name of the parent (collection) XML element.

Here are the relevant portions of my classes:

```
@Root(name="environment")
public class Environment
{ 
    @ElementListUnion(value={
        @ElementList(entry="attraction", type=Attraction.class, name="effects"),
        @ElementList(entry="repulsion", type=Repulsion.class, name="effects")
        })  
    private List<Effect> mEffects;

    // Omitted for brevity
}

public abstract class Effect
{

    // Abstract methods

    public abstract void apply(Entity pEntity1, Entity pEntity2, double pDT);
}

@Root
public class Attraction extends Effect
{
    @Override
    public void apply(Entity pEntity1, Entity pEntity2, double pDT)
    {
        // Omitted for brevity
    }
}

@Root
public class Repulsion extends Effect
{
    @Override
    public void apply(Entity pEntity1, Entity pEntity2, double pDT)
    {
        // Omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Ideally, the XML I'm trying to generate would look like this:

```
<environment>
   <effects>
      <attraction/>
      <repulsion/>
   </effects>
</environment>
```

with no class names embedded in it.

If I use a single @ElementList, not an @ElementListUnion, like so:

```
@ElementList(entry="attraction", type=Attraction.class, name="effects")
private List<Effect> mEffects;
```

I can generate this:

```
   <effects class="java.util.ArrayList">
      <attraction/>
   </effects>
```

But I can't seem to extend this to work for two subclasses.  It seems to me that the code at the top should do close to what I want, except for the java.util.ArrayList attribute.  But it actually throws an exception:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Duplicate annotation of name 'effects' on @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementListUnion(value=[@org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(entry=attraction, inline=false, data=false, name=effects, type=class net.keigwin.entities.Attraction, required=true, empty=true), @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(entry=repulsion, inline=false, data=false, name=effects, type=class net.keigwin.entities.Repulsion, required=true, empty=true)]) on field 'mEffects' private java.util.List net.keigwin.entities.Environment.mEffects
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.StructureBuilder.union(StructureBuilder.java:225)
...
```

Clearly, it doesn't like me specifying the name attribute on both of the @ElementList annotations.  I can take those out, but then the XML element "effects" generates as "mEffects", which I want to avoid.

I've read the docs and tutorial, googled, tried various things and can't find an alternative that works.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!